# Create views of model instances in Django

Tags: django

I am looking for some conceptual guidance on how I should go about implementing the following system.

I currently have a search facility that can return a list of model instances, e.g. if my Model is Cats, my search returns a list of all the Cats in the database.

**What I would like to achieve is to assign a url to each of the instances of my Model, such that the user can click on it when the search results are returned and be taken to a page which is populated with other relevant information pertaining to that instance of the Model. This system must be dynamic, as my database may contain hundreds or thousands of entries.**

As I understand it, I will require the following:

- A dynamic assignment of URLs to each instance of the model
- A URL config that passes the unique url of each instance to a view
- A view which can decipher which instance of the Model the URL points
  to and which dynamically populates a template with the relevant
  information

However, as I am a very new user of Django and python in general, I am not sure how this will all fit together. **I am especially uncertain about how to assign and route the urls.** Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank-you in advance!

P.S. Please note I'm not really looking for code, just perhaps a workflow or some other representation of how this system could work.

**///////EDIT///////**

Hi guys, thanks for all the responses. If it is ok, I would just like to ask for some additional help before I close this question out.

I took a look at the answers and had a quick stab at creating a solution. However, I believe I am having some issues with the get_absolute_url function, which seems to be returning either nothing or an empty string (cant tell).

Here is my rudimentary code:

**MODELS.py**

```
class Cats(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "catspage", self.name
```

**RESULTS.html**

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
    <p>
        <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object }}</a>
    </p>
{% empty %}
        <p>No results found.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**URLS.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^CatsView/(?P<name>-[w]+)/$', views.CatsView.as_view(), name='catspage'))
```

**VIEWS.py**

```
from django.views import generic


class CatsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Cats
    template_name = 'catsdb/object.html'
```

So, the way this works is that another view outputs to a page called results.html the results from my search function, i.e. `result.object` above.

So, in this template, each result should then link to its absolute url, defined in models.py. There is a then a generic view DetailView which, through the URL config, should route the absolute urls to a page object.html.

The bug: links are blank, url is empty.

Comment: There are no complicated requirements here, this is just standard URL routing: the tutorial tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Hi there, could you tell me if I have routed the URLs correctly?

Comment: Should be `r'^CatsView/(?P<name>\w+)/$'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has built in views to do exactly what you are trying to do!

Combining [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) should fulfill your requirements.  The documentation links provide urlconf examples.

You can use `ListView` to get all the `Cat` instances in your system, and render them.  Django has a convention of using an model instance method called [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) to get the link to view an individual instance. That link should point to the `DetailView` you set up to render `Cat` instances.

1. Use `ListView` to load all the `Cat` instances
2. Render cat instances with a link to the `DetailView` using `get_absoulte_url`
3. Use `DetailView` to render an individual `Cat` instance.

The important thing is, django provides all the tools (in the form of ClassBasedViews) to accomplish what you outlined in your question

Comment: This is indeed exactly what you need, class based view have been made for this usecase.

Comment: Thank-you for your response, this is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies that it is clearly in the documentation, I just find it difficult to unpick it sometimes. I am using Haystack-Whoosh as a search engine which is outputting the results, I suppose I could just add the link using get_absolute_url in the results. It seems I will also need to update my model with an @models.permalink function as in Louis' response as below. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi there, sorry to ask for more help but I have edited my post with an implementation of your answer. I have a bug that I believe is to do with get_absolute_url, returning nothing/an empty string. Any help would be wonderful, thanks!

Comment: i think permalink is expecting the second param to be an iterable of params `return ('catspage', [self.name])` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink

Comment: I made the alteration but sadly no change! Notably, I can use result.object.pk to output the pk's on that template, so it would seem that the object is at least capable of being queried.

Comment: @Sirrah if its a detail view `name` might be better unique?

Comment: Btw, it was just a typo in the end, sorry! I have marked this correct as it was correct. This guidance was excellent, thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use models.permalink to define the object's url.

```
from django.db import models

class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('cats_detail', [self.pk])
```

You can then use generic views and create the "cat_detail" named url.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

In the template: `<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a>`

Comment: Hey man, I edited my post but have a bug with my implementation, I would be super grateful if you could take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example of how I usualy do this. For example, I could use the cat's name as a slug for my url addresses.

See if it could help:

```
#models.py
from django import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db.models import signals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('see-cat',
        kwargs=(
        {'slug':self.slug})

    )

#Signals
def slug_pre_save(signal, instance, sender, **kwargs):
    """
    This is a pre-save signal. It will put a value into slugify before it is saved on the model.
    """
    if not instance.slug:

        slug = slugify(instance.name)
        new_slug = slug
        cont = 0

        while sender.objects.filter(slug=new_slug).exclude(id=instance.id).count() > 0:
            cont +=1
            new_slug = '%s-%d' % (slug,cont)

        instance.slug = new_slug

#Now I gonna connect the signal and the Cat Class
signals.pre_save.connect(slug_pre_save, sender=Cat)

#urls.py
url(r'^see-cat/(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$',
        'your_see_cat_view',name='see-cat'),
```